# CodeIgniter Restserver doesn't work with specific URL's

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am using this [Restserver](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) in combination with CodeIgniter.

It seems to work pretty well except when I use URL's like these;
mydomain.com/api/example/1234/

wherein 1234 is the ID I'm requesting.

Code like this doesn't seem to work:

```
class Example extends REST_Controller {
    public function index_get() {
        print($this->get("example"));
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether it is a GET or POST request. There must be a way I can just retrieve the ID from the URL..

Comment: What does `$this->get('id')` echoes in `index_get()`?

Comment: Nothing, because the index_get() isn't even called at all: `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}`

Comment: Could you try renaming your method to `example_get()` instead of `index_get()` ?

Comment: Sounds logical but if I do that the main URL doesn't even work anymore (the URl without the appended ID, e.g. mydomain.com/api/example)

Answer (score 0):

The URL's segments should equal to these:

```
api = Controller
example = Resource
```

Parameters must be in key-value pairs:

```
id = Key
1234 = Value
```

It seems that your 1234 is treaded as a key, but with no value for it. Try to change your URL to the following: `mydomain.com/api/example/id/1234/`, which would translate to: `mydomain.com/controller/resource/key/value/`

There is also a very detailed tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

**EDIT:**
Since your controller is in a sub-folder, your URL's segments should be constructed like this:

```
api/example = Controller
user = Resource // basically the method name + the http method e.g. user_get(), or user_post(). I just made 'user' up, for your app can be whatever it is that people will access via your api
```

Parameters must be provided as key-value pairs:

```
id = Key
1234 = Value
```

So then your URL would look like this: `mydomain.com/api/example/user/id/1234/`

Comment: Yes I know this. I just can't really change the request URL since I am not the person who codes the requests being made ;) Will need to stick to some clever routing.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of a GET REQUEST you just define the parameters in the header of the function like this:

```
public function index_get($param) {
    print($param);
}
```

if you want to make it optional then:

```
public function index_get($param="") {
    if ($param=="") {
       print("No Parameters!");
    } else {
       print($param);
    }
}
```

If I want to send "POST" parameters, I just create a POST METHOD and receive them as such...

```
public function index_post() {
$params = $this->post();
if (isset($param['id'])) {
   print($param['id']);
} else {
   print("No Parameters!");
}
```

}